# Treat arguments as input stream in bash

Tags: bash

Is there any bash trick that allows giving some parameters in command line to a program that gets its inputs via input stream? Something like this:

```
program < 'a=1;b=a*2;'
```

but < needs a file input stream.

Answer (score 6):

For very short here-documents, there are also here-strings:

```
program <<< "a=1;b=a*2"
```

Answer (score 2):

I think

```
echo 'a=1;b=a*2;' | program
```

is what you need. This process is called ["piping"](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~mamrak/CIS762/pipes_lab_notes.html)

As a side note: doing the opposite (i.e. piping other programs output as arguments) could be done with [`xargs`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?xargs)

Answer (score 1):

`echo` works great. The other answer is Here-documents [1]

```
program <<EOF
a=1;b=a*2;
EOF
```

I use echo when I have one very short thing on one line, and heredocs when I have something that requires newlines.

[1] http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Answer (score 0):

```
shopt -s expand_aliases

alias 'xscript:'='<<:ends'

xscript: bc | anotherprog | yetanotherprog ...

    a=1;b=a*2;

:ends
```

Took me a year to hack this one out. Premium bash script here fellas. Give respect where due please :)

I call this little 'diddy' xscript because you can expand bash variables and substitutions inside of the here document.

```
alias 'script:'='<<":ends"'
```

The above version does not expand substitutions.

```
xscript: cat

The files in our path are: `ls -A`

:ends
```

---

```
script: cat

The files in our path are: `ls -A`

:ends
```

---

I'm not finished!

```
source <(xscript: cat
    echo \$BASH "hello world, I'mma script genius!"
    echo You can thank me now $USER
:ends
)
```

Comment: Just call me the Bash Master ;)